# get a List of List object and how to handle it in html with django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

index.html

```
{% block content %}
    {{playerList}}
    {% for player in playerList %}
        {{player.value.indexOf(0)}}
        {% empty %}
            <tr>
                <td class="bg-light text-center font-italic" colspan="3">You haven't registered any players yet.</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`playerList` is a list of lists,  which is returned from views.py file.
 i.e `playerList=[["chamo",'1'],["gir",'2'],["frt",'2']]`

if I want to get the "chamo" from `playerList`, how should I write it in html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do `{{ player.0 }}`.

Comment: can you help for this one...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614593/tournament-draw-with-bye